# How to restrict sharing of a folder on Onedrive for business using REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, rest, onedrive-for-business

Using SharePoint REST API(App only token), I want to restrict sharing of a folder(or file) on onedrive for business to with in an organization.

For example, A file is shared with "user1@domain.com" and "user2@domain.com", Now I want to **remove** "user1@domain.com" from the list of shared users.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to submit a command through the REST API to restrict folder access? Or are you just trying to make sure nobody else in your organization shares the file/folder with people outside of the organization? A little more clarification please :)

Comment: I am writing a python application using SharePoint REST API so I want to restrict folder access using REST API